# Asp.net method with generic parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have a generic `APIResponse<T>` object that wraps the result of an API call:

```
public class APIError
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class APIResponse<T>
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public APIError Error { get; set; }
    public bool HasError
    {
        get { return Error != null; }
    }
}
```

I have a method that calls an API:

```
public APIResponse<string> GetUserName()
{
    APIResponse<string> response = new APIResponse<string>();

    try
    {
        // make http request
        response.Result = httpResponse;
    }
    catch
    {
        response.Error = new APIError { ErrorMessage = "Some error occurred" };
    }

    return response;
}

// I call the method like this
APIResponse<string> userNameResponse = GetUserName();

// i need to handle the apiResponse
HandleAPIResponse(userNameResponse);
```

I want to create a generic method that inspects the `APIResponse<T>` object, and throws an exception if it has an error, but i can't make it work without specifying the result type:

```
public void HandleAPIResponse(APIResponse<T> apiResponse)
{
    if (apiResponse.HasError)
        throw new Exception(apiResponse.Error.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Can i make a method that accepts `APIResponse<T>` as parameter, but without specifying the type of T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method definition should be as follows:

```
public void HandleAPIResponse<T>(APIResponse<T> apiResponse)
{
    if (apiResponse.HasError)
        throw new Exception(apiResponse.Error.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Ant there is no way of calling the method without specifying the type of `T`?

Comment: The actual invocation will always be with `T` referring to some particular type. However, I don't see how that is a problem for you.

Comment: That's right, i just tested it. When i call the method, i don't have to specify the type of `T`

Comment: but anyway this still requires the compiler to know the actual type of T. If you want to be able to do the same thing from a context when that is not available then consider defining a non generic interface with the APIError property and make your generic class implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I am wrong but I don't think that will be possible as that will assume an Overloaded style type and would be referencing a different type.